# How can I write a program to print the prime number from an array which has its index also a prime number

Tags: c, arrays, indexing, primes

How I can improvise the below code find the prime no.s from an array whose index is also a prime no.
This is my basic code :

```
#include <stdio.h>  
main() {

  int n, i, c = 0;
  printf("Enter any number n:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  /*logic*/
  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (n % i == 0) {
         c++;
      }
  }
  if (c == 2) {
    printf("n is a Prime number");
  }
  else {
     printf("n is not a Prime number");
  }
  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: first of all it's unclear what you're asking. Second, you can optimize that `for` loop heavily: Start with `i = 2`, end at `i<n`, if your modulo matches then it's not a prime, else it is.

Comment: I dont think its a unclear. Please read it twice

Comment: It is unclear. Your post doesn't even contain a question, just the title. Your supplied code doesn't necessarily have anything to do with what your question title asks for (except for being related to prime numbers).

What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: IMO: this question should be in the code review rather than here, as it is asking us to review the code, not asking us what is wrong with the code that it does not work.

Comment: It appears the question is: Given `a[]` and `i`, `for (i=2; !IsPrime(a[i]; ) { while (!IsPrime(++i)); } printf("%u", a[i]);`,  All that is left is to write `IsPrime(unsigned x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided can be optimized like this (It doesn't work for 2 and 3 though).

```
bool is_prime( int n )
{

  if ( n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0 ) {
    // If multiple of 2 or 3 it's not a prime
    return false;
  }

  // Search for divisors from 5 to only sqrt(n)
  // Example: 36: (1*36) (2*18) (3*12) (6*6) (12*3) (18*2) (36*1)
  for ( int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6 ) {
    // Check only odd numbers
    if ( n % i == 0 || n % ( i + 2 ) == 0 ) {
      // i+4 is not checked cause it's a multiple of 3
      // i is increased by 6 (multiple of 3) and the first i+4 = 9
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

You use the above function to find and store the prime numbers which are less or equal to the prime size of the array. Then for each found prime p you check if array[p] is prime with the same function.